# How to add css for specific input type text

Tags: html, css, input, field

When I was trying to add some input fields with css

I got a problem

I couldn't make more than one css for some input fields

this is the fields I have

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" />
<input type="text" name="lastName" />
```

and the css is

```
input
{
   background-image:url('images/fieldBG.gif');
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
   border: 0px solid;
   height:25px;
   width:235px;
}
```

I want to make the first field (firstName) with this css

```
input
{
   background-image:url('images/fieldBG.gif');
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
   border: 0px solid;
   height:25px;
   width:235px;
}
```

and the second one (lastName) with this css

```
input
{
   background-image:url('images/fieldBG2222.gif');
   background-repeat:repeat-x;
   border: 0px solid;
   height:25px;
   width:125px;
}
```

help please :-)

Comment: [css selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What HTML/CSS would you use to create a text input with a background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526548/what-html-css-would-you-use-to-create-a-text-input-with-a-background)

Comment: @Musa -- This one is a bit easier to read.  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the ID selector.

CSS:

```
input{
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border: 0px solid;
    height:25px;
    width:125px;
}

#firstname{
    background-image:url('images/fieldBG.gif');
}
#lastname{
    background-image:url('images/fieldBG2222.gif');
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ID="firstname" name="firstName" />    
<input type="text" ID="lastname" name="lastName" />
```

All your inputs will be styled with the generic input style, and the two special ones will have the styling specified by the ID selector.

Comment: This works, but it's generally bad practice to style with ID's. The below answer is a much better way to accomplish the task OP is trying to do.

Comment: I disagree.  Applying CSS to an ID instead of a class is exactly for this type of situation -- A one-off.  Don't abstract a lone use case!

Answer (score 96):

You can style by type or name the form elements using CSS.

```
input[type=text] {
    //styling
}
input[name=html_name] {
    //styling
}
```

Comment: In this case html_name is firstName/lastName

Comment: but you should put quotation marks around the value (not sure if it works without). Like `input[type="text]` - That's how I have always used it..

Comment: @DRP96 practically right, I just wrote a generic statement (the quotes should be implicitly added).

Comment: I don't know why this answer was not accepted.

Comment: this solution works on Firefox only.

Answer (score 5):

You have to change your HTML file:

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" /> 
<input type="text" name="lastName" />
```

...to:

```
<input type="text" id="FName" name="firstName" />
<input type="text" id="LName" name="lastName" />
```

And modify your CSS file to:

```
input {
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    border: 0px solid; 
    height:25px; 
    width:125px;
}


#FName {
    background-image:url('images/fieldBG.gif');
}


#LName {
    background-image:url('images/fieldBG2222.gif');
}
```

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 4):

Add an 'id' tag to each of your inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" />
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" />
```

then you can use the #selector in CSS to grab each one.

```
input {
  background-repeat:repeat-x; 
  border: 0px solid;
  height:25px;
}

#firstName {
  background-image:url('images/fieldBG.gif');
  width:235px;
}

#lastName {
  background-image:url('images/fieldBG2222.gif');
  width:125px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Classes to style. they are a better solution. using classes you can style each input type individually.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .classnamehere {
                //Styling;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input class="classnamehere" type="text" name="firstName" />
    </body>
</html>
```