# add style to the entered text in input field

Tags: css

please tell me how can I add a style padding-left or margin-left to the text that was entered in input field

```html
 <input name="keyword" type="text" placeholder="Job title, Keywords or Company Name"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add css for specific input type text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589304/how-to-add-css-for-specific-input-type-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are multiple ways to add style.

most preferable is

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" class="txtCSS" placeholder="Job title, Keywords or Company Name"/>
```

and then add style to that class like,

```
.txtCSS{
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    //you can add more styles if you require.
    }
```

second way is to bind css inline like these, but it's not preferable and mostly used when need to apply style on page only.

```
<input name="keyword" type="text" Style="margin-left:10px; padding-left:10px;" placeholder="Job title, Keywords or Company Name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
input {
  padding-left: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<input name="keyword" type="text" placeholder="Job title, Keywords or Company Name"/>
```

Comment: Robert you're rite. One more question. I'm trying to do the following thing: I've added a focus style to input field (input:focus{padding-left:20px}). I also added a style for placeholder text (padding-left:20px). When I place a cursor to this field, the placeholder text moves left from cursor. So I need to write a text from that very plase, where placeholder is.

Comment: The placeholdes can't have paddings. I'm not sure what you are doing. Could you please add your code?

Answer (score 0):

you can add class or id to particular input and you can give style to it.

```css
.abcd{
  padding-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<input name="keyword" type="text" class="abcd" placeholder="Job title, Keywords or Company Name"/>
```